# Java - Convert ENUM1 to ENUM2 directly

Tags: java, enums, java-7

I want to know if it is possible to convert ENUM1 to ENUM2 withou methods (directly):

```
public enum BusinessUnit {
    ONE( "ONE" ),
    TWO( "TWO" ),
}

public enum BUSINESS_UNIT {
        ONE,
        TWO,
}
```

And Then:

```
BusinessUnit bu = BusinessUnit.valueOf("ONE");
BUSINESS_UNIT bu2 = bu;
```

It's possible?

UPDATE:

I'm dont want to create any methods to convert, I want to know if:

- Its possible
- And what version of SDK its possible

Thanks again...

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Here: Type mismatch: cannot convert from BusinessUnit to BUSINESS_UNIT (JDK 7.51)

Comment: BusinessUnit != BUSINESS_UNIT

Comment: So, you have your answer: no, it's not possible. You'll need a method to transform one type into the other.

Answer (score 2):

Or, just use the instance

```
public enum BusinessUnit {
    ONE( BUSINESS_UNIT.ONE ),
    TWO( BUSINESS_UNIT.TWO );

    private final BUSINESS_UNIT unit;

    BusinessUnit(BUSINESS_UNIT unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public BUSINESS_UNIT getUnit()
    {
        return unit;
    }
}

public enum BUSINESS_UNIT {
        ONE,
        TWO,
}
```

and to get it: `BusinessUnit.(ONE/TWO).getUnit()` will return `BUSINESS_UNIT ONE/TWO`

> I'm dont want to create any methods to convert,
>
> I want to know if:
>
> Its possible
>
> And what version of SDK its possible

No. `BusinessUnit` is an `enum` and `BUSINESS_UNIT` is another `enum`. They don't have anything in common and you cannot pass from one to another without use a method.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this in the below way

```
static BUSINESS_UNIT BUSINESS_UNITTOBusinessUnit(BusinessUnit value) {
    return BUSINESS_UNIT.values()[value.ordinal()];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that with interfaces:

```
public interface BusinessUnitName {
    public String name();
}

public enum BusinessUnit implements BusinessUnitName {
    ONE,
    TWO,
}

public enum BUSINESS_UNIT implements BusinessUnitName {
    ONE,
    TWO,
}

....

BusinessUnitName bu = BusinessUnit.valueOf("ONE");
BusinessUnitName bu2 = bu;
System.out.println(bu2.name());
```

The interface declares the bare minimum needed for an object that represents a business unit. The two enum classes implement that interface (enums already implement a function called `name()`). Code which is concerned with business units should stick with using the `BusinessUnitName` interface. It shouldn't look too closely at `BusinessUnitName` objects to see how they're actually implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You have to *call* methods but you neither have to *define* new methods nor to define *interfaces*. If I understood correctly you want to convert from one enum type to another by matching name:

```
public class ConversionTest {
    enum BusinessUnit {
        ONE, TWO
    }
    enum BUSINESS_UNIT {
        ONE, TWO
    }
    @Test public void convert_BUSINESS_UNIT_to_BusinessUnit() {
        assertEquals(BusinessUnit.ONE, BusinessUnit.valueOf(BUSINESS_UNIT.ONE.name()));
    }
    @Test public void convert_BusinessUnit_to_BUSINESS_UNIT() {
        assertEquals(BUSINESS_UNIT.ONE, BUSINESS_UNIT.valueOf(BusinessUnit.ONE.name()));
    }
}
```